# listings package conflict with polyglossia

Tags: xetex, listings, polyglossia

I cut down the minimum working example; I am using `XeTeX`. The following code does not work unless I comment the line `\setotherlanguage{arabic}` or the line `\usepackage{listings}`. When I compile the following example it opens the file `xelatex/bidi/listings-xetex-bidi.def` and points at:

```
\ProvidesFile{listings-xetex-bidi.def}[2017/01/14 v1.4 bidi adaptations for listings package for XeTeX engine]
\lst@Key{captiondirection}{textdirection}{%
    \lstKV@SwitchCases{#1}%
    {textdirection&\\%
     RTL&\chardef\bidi@lst@caption@direction\@ne\\%
     LTR&\chardef\bidi@lst@caption@direction\z@%
    }{\PackageError{Listings}{direction #1 unknown}\@ehc}}
```

and gives me the error message:

```
! Package Listings Error: direction textdirection unkown.
```

The code:

```
\documentclass[11pt, b6paper, landscape, oneside]{memoir}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}

\begin{document}

Hello

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your example compiles for me. What error do you get?

Comment: With XeLaTeX the MWE compiles fine for me. With LuaLaTeX I get complaints about `\luatexpardir`. What error do you get? Can you show us the `.log` file?

Comment: Thanks so much for your fast reply; I updated the post to contain the error message and more details

Comment: Mhh my version of `listings-xetex-bidi.def` is newer than yours, I have `listings-xetex-bidi.def  2018/09/15 v1.5 bidi adaptations for listings package for XeTeX engine`. Maybe an update can help you.

Comment: But I update Archlinux daily, which updates LaTeX as well. What update should I do? BTW, this problem recently occurred; same code ran well months ago!

Comment: Any help regarding updating  `listings`? Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: @Waleed A. Yousef  This problem has solved in bidi-33.2. please see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/450824/problem-with-bidi-in-polyglossia  and update the bidi package.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was a bug solved by an update to the bidi package